# Deploy local bundle to existing machine

Tags: juju, lxd

In my current juju model I have one machine with a few containers

```
Machine    State 
14         started 
14/lxd/2   started 
14/lxd/20  started
```

I want to deploy a local bundle with 2 local charms. My `bundle.yaml` looks like this:

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    charm: /home/user/charms/trusty/elasticsearch
    num_units: 1
    to: ['lxd:14']
  metricbeat:
    charm: /home/user/charms/trusty/metricbeat
series: trusty
relations:
  - - "elasticsearch:client"
    - "metricbeat:elasticsearch"
```

Now I want my elasticsearch charm in a LXD container on machine 14 but when i run `juju deploy ~/elastic5-bundle` I get the following error:

```
ERROR the provided bundle has the following errors:
placement "lxd:14" refers to a machine not defined in this bundle
```

But when I add machine 14 in my bundle.yaml, a new machine is created instead of the charm being deployed to machine 14. Any possible solution to deploy a charm in a bundle to an existing machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest Juju version (2.3) I noticed that there is now a flag that you can use when deploying a bundle. I found the documentation [here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.3/charms-bundles#recycling-machines):

To have a bundle use a model's existing machines, as opposed to creating new machines, the `--map-machines=existing` option is used. In addition, to specify particular machines for the mapping, comma-separated values of the form 'bundle-id=existing-id' can be passed where the bundle-id and the existing-id refer to top level machine IDs.

For example, consider a bundle whose YAML file is configured with machines 1, 2, 3, and 4, and a model containing machines 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. The following deployment would use existing machines 1 and 2 for bundle machines 1 and 2 but use existing machine 4 for bundle machine 3 and existing machine 5 for bundle machine 4:

`juju deploy some-bundle --map-machines=existing,3=4,4=5`

Answer (score 2):

You can't deploy charms on existing machines by using juju deploy command. Machines should be defined in the bundle for that to work.

Your bundle should look like this:

```
machines:
  '14':
    constraints: <any constraint for example tags=machine14 or mem=3048 or arch=amd64>

services:
  elasticsearch:
    charm: /home/user/charms/trusty/elasticsearch
    num_units: 1
    to: ['lxd:14']
  metricbeat:
    charm: /home/user/charms/trusty/metricbeat
series: trusty
relations:
  - - "elasticsearch:client"
    - "metricbeat:elasticsearch"
```

It is probably possible using **juju-deployer**. Install juju-deployer by adding this repo:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tvansteenburgh/ppa
```

Define the bundle as:

```
phase1:
  services:
    elasticsearch:
      charm: /home/user/charms/trusty/elasticsearch
      num_units: 1
      to: ['lxd:14']
    metricbeat:
      charm: /home/user/charms/trusty/metricbeat
  series: trusty
  relations:
    - - "elasticsearch:client"
      - "metricbeat:elasticsearch"
```

Now, deploy by running the following command:

```
$ juju-deployer -c bundle.yaml phase1
```